# How to get PHAsset from HTTP URL?

Tags: http, url, swift3, ios10, phasset

I have a remote URL/HTTP URL of a video. How can I get the `PHAsset` from the HTTP URL and use that `PHAsset` element?

Comment: Did you solve it?